# Inequality for a transient state.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let y be a transient state. Show that for all x
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P^n(x,y) \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P^n(y,y)$$

Hint: Use $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P^n(x,y)=\frac{\rho_{xy}}{1-\rho_{yy}}$

I tried to sum one and use the property $0 \leq \rho_{xy} \leq 1$ but I could not conclude. Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't $\sum_{i=1}^\infty P^n(x,y)$ obviously diverge?

Comment: mmm why? y is transient so there is no problem, right?

Comment: this doesn't make any sense $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P^n(x,y) \leq \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P^n(y,y)$ the indexing in the sum is over i, but $i$ doesn't show up in there, only $n$ and some y, evidently neither of which are related to $i$

Comment: my bad, it has to be n instead of i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it...
We know that
    $$P^0(x,y)=P[X_0=y|X_0=x]=\begin{cases}
         1 & if x=y\\
         0 & if x \neq y 
         \end{cases}$$
In other hand , let's see that
    \begin{align*}
  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P^n(y,y)&=P^0(y,y)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P^n(y,y)\\
  &=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P^n(y,y)\\
  &=1+\frac{\rho_{yy}}{1-\rho_{yy}} \tag{Hint}\\
  &=\frac{1}{1-\rho_{yy}}.
 \end{align*}

Therefore, 
    \begin{align*}
  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P^n(x,y)&=P^0(x,y)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P^n(x,y)\\
  &=0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P^n(x,y)\\
  &=\frac{\rho_{xy}}{1-\rho_{yy}} \tag{Hint}\\
  &\leq \frac{1}{1-\rho_{yy}}. \tag{$0 \leq \rho_{xy} \leq 1$}\\
  &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P^n(y,y).
 \end{align*}

Hence, 
    $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P^n(x,y) \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P^n(y,y).$$
Q.E.D.